# how to generate inputs for benchmark programs when doing random testing

Tags: testing, random

The benchmark programs used in papers about random testing usually takes 
numbers as input. It's easy to random generate numbers but the inputs of real-world programs are usually strings or files. How to generate complex inputs when doing random testing?

Another question is that I'm currently implementing a framework for random testing. Maybe the first step is to test programs which take numbers as input. How can I find such benchmark programs?

I want to test c/c++ programs and need to generate the arguments for the main function.

Comment: The easiest way would be to have a list or file of the items from which you could randomly select. otherwise you are probably going to require a generator which depending on what the objects you are passing you may need to write yourself.

Comment: Suppose I just have the developer's test suite, is there a tool to learn from the test suite and then generate new test input?

Comment: You really need to give us more than that. What language are the tests coded in? what do you need to generate? etc